# Missing background magic command (%bg ) in IPython

Tags: ipython

The IPython documentation refers to a %bg magic function. However when I try to use this in 0.12.1 it is not found. Am I missing something obvious?

```
In [38]: %bg
ERROR: Magic function `bg` not found.
```

%lsmagic gives:

```
In [46]: %lsmagic
Available magic functions:
%alias  %autocall  %automagic  %bookmark  %cd  %clear  %cls  %colors  %config %connect_info  %debug  %dhist  %dirs  %doctest_mode  %ed  %edit  %env  %gui  %guiref  %hist  %history  %install_default_config  %install_profiles  %less  %load_ext  %loadpy  %logoff  %logon  %logstart  %logstate  %logstop  %lsmagic  %macro  %magic  %more  %notebook  %page  %pastebin  %pdb  %pdef  %pdoc  %pfile  %pinfo  %pinfo2  %popd  %pprint  %precision  %profile  %prun  %psearch  %psource  %pushd  %pwd  %pycat  %pylab  %qtconsole  %quickref  %recall  %rehashx  %reload_ext  %rep  %rerun  %reset  %reset_selective  %run  %save  %sc  %store  %sx  %tb  %time  %timeit  %unalias  %unload_ext  %who  %who_ls  %whos  %xdel  %xmode
```

Comment: Supposedly this magic function should be available in v0.12.1 Are you sure you don't have another, older version installed? At the command line try: `ipython -Version`

Comment: Where is this in the documentation? It's possible the documentation is out of date.

Comment: I think the official 0.12.1 docs are fine.. they don't mention `%bg`. I must have seen an out of date reference to it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%bg` magic has not been restored since the Great IPython Refactoring of 0.11, but the library code with which it would be reimplemented [has been updated](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/856).

This is an [open Issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/844), and pull requests are always welcome.